# Atom Marker for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there anything akin to Atom's [markers](https://atom.io/docs/api/v0.208.0/Marker) in VSCode?

I have a [VSCode extension](https://github.com/danseethaler/vscode-tab-through-selections) that allows you to tab through multiple cursors/selections and edit each one individually. In order to correctly support this I need to be able to update the original multi-cursor selections if there are new lines added, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Search the extensions for "bookmarks" - there a couple of them.

Comment: Interesting thought @Mark. I found a class in the  [numbered-bookmarks](https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-numbered-bookmarks/blob/master/src/Sticky.ts) extension that manually implements what I'm looking for. Not real promising that there's an api solution...